# how to get google api key for device

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps

I have created an application in Android based on Google Maps. I got an API key and it's running successfully in the emulator but when I run it on a device, it's showing a force close message.  Can someone please explain how to get an API key for use on a device and whether I have to get an API key specifically for device use at all?

My Java code:

```
setContentView(R.layout.mapview);
mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);       
mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

String coordinates[] = {"9.966667", "78.166667"};
double lat = Double.parseDouble(coordinates[0]);
double lng = Double.parseDouble(coordinates[1]);
GeoPoint  p = new GeoPoint((int) (lat * 1E6),(int) (lng * 1E6));

MapController mapController = mapView.getController();

mapController.setCenter(p);
mapController.animateTo(p);
mapController.setZoom(12);
```

My layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <com.google.android.maps.MapView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:apiKey="myapikey" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Logcat error:

```
 Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x1080215
```

This issue is a blocker on my project so I cannot move forward until it is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Read the [documentation](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/mapkey.html)

edit: okay I'm quoting the documentation for you

> When you are preparing to release your
>   application, however, note that you
>   must sign your application with a
>   suitable cryptographic key, rather
>   than the SDK debug key. That means
>   that you will also need to register
>   your application's release certificate
>   with the Google Maps service. After
>   you've done so, you will receive a new
>   Maps API Key that is uniquely
>   associated with your release
>   certificate. To enable the MapView
>   elements in your application to work
>   after release, you must remember to
>   change the Maps API Key for all
>   MapViews in your application so that
>   they refer to the Key associated with
>   your release certificate (rather than
>   your debug certificate).

Fine read the following section "Getting the MD5 Fingerprint of Your Signing Certificate"

```
$ keytool -list -alias alias_name -keystore my-release-key.keystore
```

Comment: I have already seen that documentation. With the help of this document only i have created api key for my emulator and its running successfully but for releasing they have given as before release i have to get api key. I'm confused at this point only. whether i have to follow the same way when i created debug key or it has some other way to create api key?

Comment: See my edit, did you miss this paragraph in the documentation or something?

Comment: I have seen sir..can you please explain procedure since i am new to android application i didnt know about releasing my application. my seniors said they will create key for release application through eclipse they have changed application into Signed application using android tools. They too dont know how to create api key for release. can you please explain in detail?